# Cloudinary generated hidden input value

Tags: cloudinary

I'm using node.js to generate a direct upload file tag for Cloudinary

```
cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag('coverImage', {html: {'class': 'cloudinary-coverImage', format: 'jpg'}})
```

After uploading, a hidden `input` tag like this is auto generated at the end of the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="coverImage" value="image/upload/v1431361091/bns8et8ksrx3km5esdpj.jpg#d36285fd9bcccd5a2034b22ebf69d867fcee0bbc">
```

I realize that the input value is not exactly the public id like said in the docs, so when I store it in the DB, this will not generate a proper image

```
cloudinary.image(abc.coverImage)
```

How can I get the image's exact public id in the hidden input value?

Comment: This also really baffles me... why doesn't the Cloudinary gem just save the public ID? Not doing so causes the cl_image_tag method not to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

The format of the hidden input tag's value is `{resource_type}/{type}/v{version}/{public_id}.{format}#{signature}`. You need the public_id, which in your example is `bns8et8ksrx3km5esdpj`.

## Details

The value of the hidden field includes the resource type, version, public id and the signature of the uploaded image. The `public_id` is the last part of the URI before the Hash (#).

Refer to the [sample code](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/photo_album/controllers/photos_controller.js#L130-138), taken from the node.js [controller](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/photo_album/controllers/photos_controller.js) code, for an example of handling the upload results (to match your example above, `image_id` below should be replaced with the name you designated for the field, i.e. `coverImage`):

```js
var Photo = schema.models.Photo;
var photo = new Photo(req.body);

var image = new cloudinary.PreloadedFile(req.body.image_id);
// check that image resolved from image_id is valid
if (image.is_valid()){
  photo.image = image.toJSON();
  console.dir(photo.image)
}
photo.save().then(function(photo){
  console.log('** photo saved')
})
```

### Brower side

If you need to get the `public_id` of the image following a direct upload on the browser side, you should listen to the `"cloudinarydone"` event:

```js
$("body").on( "cloudinarydone", function(e, data) {
  console.log(data.result.public_id);
});
```